# How do you delete in java with a hash table

Tags: java, hashtable

I don't understand in this code if (before == null) Array[position] = e.next; 
how can before equals to null? it would mean that e==null no?
also, in an entry hash, there's C c, V v, and the next entryhash (so the link to the "next" one)
but if we do before.next = e.next;  then wouldn't the link be lost?

```
public V delete(C c) { 
    int positionition = indiHash(c); 
    EntryHash<C, V> e = Array[position], before = null; 
    while (e != null && !e.key.equals(c)) { 
        before = e; 
        e = e.next; 
    } 
    if (e == null) return null;
    if (before == null) Array[position] = e.next; 
    else before.next = e.next; 
    size--; 
    return e.value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`e` is the element you want to delete.

It is part of a linked list, so it potentially has an element `before` and an `e.next`.

The linked list head is stored in `Array[position]` (it is an array because there are many such lists in the hash table, one for each hash bucket), and every element has a pointer to the `next` element.

If there is no `before`, then `e` was at the head of the linked list. You can remove it by pointing the new list head at `e.next` (which can be `null`, too, meaning that the whole list is empty now).

If there is a `before`, you have to fix the list, by pointing `before.next` at `e.next`.

> how can before equals to null? it would mean that e==null no?

No. It is possible, that `e` is the head element of the list. Then the while loop is never entered and `before` remains null.

> if we do before.next = e.next; then the llink won't be lost?

Not sure what you mean. `e` will be removed from the list, but that is what you want. If the list was `BEFORE => e => NEXT` before, it will be `BEFORE => NEXT` after.